# Multiple controllers using the same route param with a default value - looking for elegant solutions

Tags: angularjs

I'm building a system in AngularJS which currently has two controllers (probably more later) which both need to work with an optional route parameter (date).  Another controller takes care of setting the date, that is, changing the route to include the date selected by the user.

I'm looking for a clean, elegant solution without repeating code.

I know I can easily do this in both controllers, to fetch the date from the route:

```
$scope.date = typeof ($routeParams.date) != 'undefined' ? $routeParams.date : '<fetch currentdate>';
```

and probably have both controllers listen to the `$locationChangeStart` event like so:

```
$scope.$on("$locationChangeStart", function(...) {
    $scope.date = <fetch from route>
});
```

But that would involve some code repetitions.  What would be a better/cleaner solution?  I thought about creating a service/factory for this but perhaps that's overkill?

Any suggestions welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, since I got no responses whatsoever to my question, I had to cook something up by myself.

Here's what I came up with.  I created a new 'Utility' service, which has a GetDate method which takes in an optional selected date:

```
myAppName.factory('utilities', function () {
    var Service = function () {
        var self = this;

        self.GetDate = function (selectedDate) {
            var date = new Date();
            return (typeof (selectedDate) != 'undefined' ? selectedDate : date.getFullYear() + '-' + (date.getMonth()+1) + '-' + date.getDate());
        }
    };

    return new Service();
});
```

Then I inject the utility service into all controllers which need the date and do this:

```
$scope.date = utilities.GetDate($routeParams.date);
```

If `$routeParams.date` is undefined, I get the current date.  Otherwise I get the date specified in the route parameter, in the format I need.

This seems to work beautifully.  The only code repetition is the above line, once in each controller which needs this information.

Feel free to suggest a better way.